# Embedded Mysql (libmysql.dll) and C# & Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, embedded-database

I'm trying to connect to a mysql database with .net framework. I've searched for an example for c# desktop app or asp.net but no result. Can anyone explain how to connect successfully to an embedded mysql database.

I've found a library here [sourceforge.net/mysqldrivercs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqldrivercs/) but don't want to use any extra code if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use some kind of connector to conect to MySql, just like you would if you wanted to connect to a Sql server database, only difference is that the assemblies for Sql Server have been built into the .net framework.

Take a look at the following links for example on connecting to MySql.

[CodeProject Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysql-db-with-c-sharp.aspx) 
[Example 2](http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html)

Comment: Actually I know how to connect via Mysql.Data.dll to a server with ip, but I don't know how to connect to a database with only libmysql.dll which do not require mysql server installed and don't have an ip.